# c# send data to dataset in another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have here a part of my code, where i send data from textboxes and datagridview to a dataset (all this in Form1)

But how i can do, that i send all these data to a dataset form (project > add new item > dataset ??

Thank you

```
private void SendData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "Order";
        dt.Columns.Add("OrderNr");
        dt.Columns.Add("Custommer");
        dt.Columns.Add("Material");
        dt.Columns.Add("MaterialCode");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataTable dtx = new DataTable();
        dtx.TableName = "Data";
        dtx.Columns.Add("Lenght");
        dtx.Columns.Add("Width");
        dtx.Columns.Add("Qty");
        dtx.Columns.Add("Texture");
        ds.Tables.Add(dtx);

        DataRow row = ds.Tables["Order"].NewRow();
        row["OrderNr"] = tbOrderNr.Text;
        row["Custommer"] = tbCustommer.Text;
        row["Material"] = tbMaterial.Text;
        row["MaterialCode"] = tbForm2MatCode.Text;
        ds.Tables["Udaje"].Rows.Add(row);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row1 = ds.Tables["Data"].NewRow();
            row1["Lenght"] = r.Cells[0].Value;
            row1["Width"] = r.Cells[1].Value;
            row1["Qty"] = r.Cells[2].Value;
            row1["Texture"] = r.Cells[3].Value;
            ds.Tables["Data"].Rows.Add(row1);
        }
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
    }
```

Comment: The Entity Framework is designed to make this kind of thing easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your forms are called `Form1` and `Form2` and you want to send something to `Form2`. You will do this:

**Approach 1**

In `Form2` create a property:

```
public DataSet DataSet {get; set; }
```

Inf `Form1`, imagine you have an instance of `Form2` called `f2`:

```
f2.DataSet = // The dataset you want to send to Form2
```

**Approach 2**

In `Form1` (not Form2), create a property like this:

```
private DataSet aDataSet;
public DataSet DataSet {get { return this.aDataSet; }}
```

Then you can access it in `Form2` using the `Form1` instance. Imagine the instance is named `f1`:

```
var f1DataSet = f1.DataSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr. [JohnG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6842716/johng) posted here very usefull answer too, but was deleted.
Thank you.

As CodingYoshi pointed out, there are several ways to pass variables between forms. It really depends on what you are doing. You could simply pass the WHOLE parent form to the child form like `Form2 f2 = new Form2(this)` where “this” is the parent `Form1` and `Form2` has a constructor with a signature like `Form2(Form1 parent)`. Inside that constructor you could assign “this” parent to a `Form2` variable like: `Form1 PARENT;` then assign it in the constructor with `PARENT = parent`;.

This would give you access to all the public variables in `Form1`. Obviously this is overkill and unnecessary if we simply want to pass a single `DataSet`. So applying this idea, it seems fairly straight forward to pass the `DataSet` in `Form1` to `Form2` Example: `Form2 f2 = new Form2(DataSet);`. Obviously you will need to set up an appropriate constructor with a `DataSet` signature. This will pass the `DataSet` to `Form2` as per the requirement.

The code below does just this with a few changes I felt would make this easier. I am guessing here, but following your code, it appears you have two (2) `DataTables`: `Order` and `Data`. The `Order` table appears to only hold ONE (1) record (row)… i.e. Order number; Customer; Material and Material Code are single entities for this `Order`. The `Order` may have one or more `Data` items i.e. Length, Width..Etc. This structure screams “make me a class”. The code below uses two (2) classes: `Order` and `OrderItem`.

`OrderItem` would be a single `Data` item in your code: “Length”, “Width” Etc.

`Order` would contain `OrderNr`, `Customer` etc. And a `List` of `OrderItem` objects to hold multiple OrderItems. Below a list is used but you could make it any data structure you may need.

This new `Order` class would be a convenient item to pass to that second form. Hope this make sense.

Barebone OrderItem class

```
public class OrderItem {
  public double Lenght { get; set; }
  public double Width { get; set; }
  public double Qty { get; set; }
  public string Texture { get; set; }

  public OrderItem(double inLength, double inWidth, double inQty, string inTexture) {
    Lenght = inLength;
    Width = inWidth;
    Qty = inQty;
    Texture = inTexture;
  }
}
```

Barebone `Order` Class – Addition method to get a `DataTable` of `OrderItems` and a string method.

```
public class Order {
  public int OrderNr { get; set; }
  public string Custommer { get; set; }
  public string Material { get; set; }
  public string MaterialCode { get; set; }
  public List<OrderItem> OrderInfo { get; set; }

  public Order(int oNum, string oCust, string oMaterial, string oMatCode) {
    OrderNr = oNum;
    Custommer = oCust;
    Material = oMaterial;
    MaterialCode = oMatCode;
    OrderInfo = new List<OrderItem>();
  }

  public DataTable GetItemsDT() {
    DataTable OrderDT = new DataTable();
    OrderDT.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(double));
    OrderDT.Columns.Add("Width", typeof(double));
    OrderDT.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(double));
    OrderDT.Columns.Add("Texture", typeof(string));
    foreach (OrderItem item in OrderInfo) {
      OrderDT.Rows.Add(item.Lenght, item.Width, item.Qty, item.Texture);
    }
    return OrderDT;
  }

  public string GetOrderString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Order: " + OrderNr + " Customer: " + Custommer + " Material: " + Material + " MatCode: " + MaterialCode);
    sb.AppendLine("-- Order Items --");
    sb.AppendLine("Length, Width, Qty, Texture");
    foreach (OrderItem item in OrderInfo) {
      sb.AppendLine(item.Lenght + ", " + item.Width + ", " + item.Qty + ", " + item.Texture);
    }
    sb.AppendLine("");
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Form1 methods `GetOrderFromTextBoxes` and `GetOrderItemsFromDGV`

```
private Order GetOrderFromTextBoxes() {
  int orderNum = 0;
  int.TryParse(tbOrderNr.Text, out orderNum);
  string cust = tbCustommer.Text;
  string mat = tbMaterial.Text;
  string code = tbForm2MatCode.Text;
  return new Order(orderNum, cust, mat, code);
}

private void GetOrderItemsFromDGV(Order inOrder) {
  double doubleValue = 0;
  double length = 0;
  double width = 0;
  double qty = 0;
  string texture = "";
  foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (!r.IsNewRow) {
      if (r.Cells[0] != null)
        double.TryParse(r.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), out doubleValue);
      length = doubleValue;
      if (r.Cells[1] != null)
        double.TryParse(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), out doubleValue);
      width = doubleValue;
      if (r.Cells[2] != null)
        double.TryParse(r.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out doubleValue);
      qty = doubleValue;
      if (r.Cells[3] != null)
        texture = r.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
      inOrder.OrderInfo.Add(new OrderItem(length, width, qty, texture));
    }
  }
}
```

Using a button click on `Form1` to use the above methods and pass the `Order` object to `Form2`

```
private void btSendOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Order thisOrder = GetOrderFromTextBoxes();
  GetOrderItemsFromDGV(thisOrder);
  Form2 f2 = new Form2(thisOrder);
  f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

`Form2` using the incoming `Order` object to fill some text boxes and set the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` by getting the `Order’s` items `DataTable` with `thisOrder.GetItemsDT();`

```
private Order thisOrder;
public Form2(Order inOrder) {
  InitializeComponent();
  thisOrder = inOrder;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tbCustommer.Text = thisOrder.Custommer;
  tbOrderNr.Text = thisOrder.OrderNr.ToString();
  tbMaterial.Text = thisOrder.Material;
  tbForm2MatCode.Text = thisOrder.MaterialCode;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = thisOrder.GetItemsDT();
}
```

Hope this helps.